# Error in Strings assignment. (C++)

Tags: c++, string, console

I've looked everywhere and I've found one for php but not c++. I'm making a little console rpg for a project in my into to c++ class and I'd like to avoid functions and/or if possible--but if not I'll use them.

Sample code:

```
int main(){
    string pName;
    string pWpnName;
    int pDamage=0;
    int wdSwrdD=1;

 if (pDamage==wdSwrdD)pWpnName="Wooden Sword";

 cout<<"Please enter a name";
 cin>>pName;

pDamage++:

cout<<"Name: "<<pName<<endl;
cout<<"Weapon: "<<pWpnName<<endl;
return 0}
```

But whenever I do this it outputs: `Name: pName` (like it's supposed to) and `Weapon:`. It just stays blank and I have a feeling it's something to do with how I'm using strings...

Comment: Change `pWpnName=="Wooden Sword"`; to `pWpnName="Wooden Sword";` You just have a typo.

Comment: pWpnName is initialize to an empty string.  It never gets change (check your if statement) so it outputs an empty string.

Comment: @AfriCoffee Also your question title is totally misleading.

Comment: If this did *not* generate a compiler warning, either you need to crank up your warning levels or use a different toolchain. ex: clang reports *"main.cpp:15:34: Equality comparison result unused"*

Answer (score 3):

You do not understand basics of how imperative languages (and C++ is one of them) work. Program executed statement by statement, and your `if` condition checks `pDamage==wdSwrdD` only once - when execution flow goes through that statement. So the fact that you increase `pDamage` later will not magically change `pWpnName` (and you need to change comparison operator `==` to assignment operator `=` in that if condition in addition to that, but I assume this is a typo).

So you most probably need a loop where execution flow is repeatedly goes through your `if` statement (that's what loops are created for), but it is difficult to say anything more based on information you provided.

Comment: Augh, I knew it was something on my part, I'm really a noob when it comes to programming...and yeah, the `==` operator was a typo. How do I make the loop go through the if(else) statement throughout the rest of the program then? Do I need to use a separate function and call it or is there a way to just keep it in main?

Comment: @AfriCoffee there are a lot of good textbooks online and in stores, I doubt I can explain it better as you need to learn from very basics.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the getline() function:

```
cout<<"Please enter a name"<<endl;
getline(cin, pName);
pDamage++;
```

The function can get a line from a stream, set std::cin as the steam argument, and assign a line input to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you've made a typo: `==` is equality comparison, while `=` is assignment.  So, your section of code should be changed:

```
if (pDamage==wdSwrdD)
    pWpnName=="Wooden Sword"; // here you're doing comparison
```

...to:

```
if (pDamage==wdSwrdD)
    pWpnName="Wooden Sword"; // here you're doing assignment
```

Most compilers should generate a warning for this behavior because it's an easy typo to make, but can be difficult to catch.

Answer (score 0):

In your program you have not initialized the strings and your are taking user input for pName and therefore it displays the name . In case pWpnName it's not initialized while declaring and the "if condition never becomes true" because you have initialized pDamage=0 and wdSwrD=1 and as we know if(0==1) is never true the string pWpnName never gets initialized to Wooden Sword so it displays blank.